# Using GitHub and Testing the Script in World of Warcraft

Tags: github, lua, world-of-warcraft

I've been coding for a year or so in .lua for an addon. I am using github now to manage changes and keep tracking code changes. My question is about Coding techniques for this use.

I am pulling my repo and then copying it for the WoW Addons folder (so I can keep changing and testing), but then I have this problem of bringing all the files back, to the git, since it goes like this:

GHub -> Pull -> Copy to Game Folder -> Edit -> Test -> Send back to Ghub.

I am looking for some Coding Techniques for making this easier so I could avoid doing the edits and tests far from the repo that I pull, so I could do this:

Ghub Pull -> Edit and test -> Commit.

I've tried to search for online ideas, but the wow addon community doesn't talk about these practical part.

Comment: Clone it into the addons folder?

Comment: You should do editing and testing inside project folder, but add extra files (created while testing) to `.gitignore` to avoid them be included in git repo.